# Which method shall be used to handle such situation in spark RDD. Explain?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

You are creating an RDD rdd1 after a lot of computation from another RDD rdd0. And then we need to use rdd1 often. The size of rdd1 is very small and we have an ample amount of RAM available on every container. Which method shall be used to handle such a situation in spark RDD. Explain?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cache` to cache the results of the computation in memory, so that it will not need to be recomputed:

```
rdd1 = # operations on rdd0
rdd1.cache()
```